# How to refactor this scala code?

Tags: scala, playframework, refactoring

I want to refactor this code into something more readable and better in general. I know that in Scala there are normally neat ways of doing things but for me it's getting a bit messy (BTW I'm using the Play library in the code). this is a snippet of my code:

```
class HomeController @Inject()
  (cc: ControllerComponents)
  (implicit val config: Configuration)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def removeIdElement(uid: String) =
    HAction(uid, "AuthEvent", 1, "login", parse.text).async {
      implicit request: Request[String] =>
        val promise = Promise[Result]()
        Future {
          val removeId = request.body.toLong
          println(s"remove id $removeId")

          promise completeWith {
            idElementsDAO.remove(removeId, uid.toLong) map {
              _ => Ok("")
            } recover {
              case t: Throwable =>
                val errorMessage: String = getMessageFromThrowable(t)
                println("remove id element failure " + errorMessage)
                BadRequest(errorMessage)
            }
          }
        } recover {
          case t: Throwable =>
            val errorMessage: String = getMessageFromThrowable(t)
            println("remove id element failure " + errorMessage)
            promise.success(BadRequest(errorMessage))
        }
        promise.future
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to start by splitting into smaller methods. The code inside future could be another different method with a good name

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler version of your code:

```
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit val config: Configuration)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def removeIdElement(uid: String) = HAction(uid, "AuthEvent", 1, "login", parse.text).async {
    implicit request: Request[String] =>

    Future {
      val removeId = request.body.toLong
      println(s"Removing id $removeId")
      removeId
    }.flatMap(id => idElementsDAO.remove(id, uid.toLong))
     .map(_ => Ok(""))
     .recover {
       case t: Throwable =>
         val errorMessage = getMessageFromThrowable(t)
         println(s"Removing id element failed: ${errorMessage}")
         BadRequest(errorMessage)
     }
  }
}
```

In the above code, a `Promise` is not needed, and the `recover` combinator is not repeated.

Comment: if there's an exception in the future returned by `idElementsDAO.remove`, this code will incorrectly still return `Ok`... because the first `map` is producing a nested future, and the `recover` call is only handling the `outer` one.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `idElementsDAO.remove` return a `Future`, this is probably more idiomatic:

```
def removeIdElement(uid: String) =
  HAction(uid, "AuthEvent", 1, "login", parse.text).async {implicit request =>
    val removeId = request.body.toLong
    println(s"remove id $removeId")

    idElementsDAO.remove(removeId, uid.toLong)
      .map(_ => NoContent) // probably more correct than `Ok("")`
      .recover {
        case t: Throwable =>
          val errorMessage: String = getMessageFromThrowable(t)
          println("remove id element failure " + errorMessage)
          BadRequest(errorMessage)
      }
  }
```

No need for the `Promise` or the call to `Future {...}` (`Future.apply`).

Keep in mind, it's probably not the best idea to directly pass the underlying error of **any** `Throwable` directly to the http client (browser?).

If you add generic error handling code to the global error handler (for unexpected errors) that logs the error and sends a generic message to the front-end, you can then write it even cleaner like this:

```
def removeIdElement(uid: String) =
  HAction(uid, "AuthEvent", 1, "login", parse.text).async {implicit request =>
    val removeId = request.body.toLong
    println(s"remove id $removeId")

    for {
      _ <- idElementsDAO.remove(removeId, uid.toLong)
    } yield NoContent
  }
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaErrorHandling